Selenium Script Not Re-Running After Countdown Ends
I have developed a Python script using Selenium to automate interactions with a website. The script is designed to log in to the website, perform certain actions, and then wait for a specific interval of time before repeating the process. However, I'm encountering an issue where the script does not re-run after the countdown timer ends.
Code:
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='selenium_log.txt',
                    filemode='a',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

next_run_time = None


def run_selenium_script():
    global next_run_time
    try:
        # Set up Chrome options
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

        # Initialize the WebDriver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

        # Navigate to the website
        driver.get("https://scarletblue.com.au/auth/login")

        # Create a WebDriverWait instance
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

        # Wait for the email input to be visible and then enter the email
        email_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
        email_input.clear()
        email_input.send_keys("your_email_here")

        # Wait for the password input to be visible and then enter the password
        password_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
        password_input.clear()
        password_input.send_keys("your_password_here")

        # Wait for the login button to be clickable and then click it
        login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn.btn-red.pull-right")))
        login_button.click()

        # Wait for the modal to become visible, to ensure the escape press closes the intended modal
        modal_xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'modal') and contains(@style, 'display: block')]"
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, modal_xpath)))

        # Simulate pressing Escape by sending keys to the body of the page
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

        # Execute JavaScript to click the element using the given selectors
        # Attempt to click using the CSS selector within shadow DOM (if present)
        driver.execute_script("""
        var shadowHost = document.querySelector('#main-container');
        var shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadowRoot || shadowHost;
        var toggleButton = shadowRoot.querySelector('i');
        if (toggleButton) {
            toggleButton.click();
        } else {
            // Fall back to other selectors if not found in shadow DOM
            var xpathToggleButton = document.evaluate(
                "//label[@class='toggle']/i",
                document,
                null,
                XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
                null
            ).singleNodeValue;
            if (xpathToggleButton) {
                xpathToggleButton.click();
            } else {
                // If the element is still not found, report an error or try other selectors
                console.error('Toggle button not found');
            }
        }
        """)

        # Check if the SweetAlert is visible and if it can be closed with the Escape key
        sweetalert_xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'sweet-alert') and contains(@class,'visible')]"
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, sweetalert_xpath)))

        # Attempt to send Escape key to the SweetAlert
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

        # If the SweetAlert did not close, find the button that closes the alert and click it
        # Usually, SweetAlert has a button with class 'confirm' or 'cancel' to close it
        try:
            # This waits for the confirm button to be clickable, which is usually used to close the alert
            confirm_button_xpath = "//button[contains(@class,'confirm')]"
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, confirm_button_xpath)))
            confirm_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, confirm_button_xpath)
            confirm_button.click()
        except Exception as e:
            # If there's no confirm button or clicking didn't work, log the exception
            print(f"Could not find or click confirm button: {e}")

        logging.info("Selenium script executed successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred during Selenium script execution: {e}")

    finally:
        driver.quit()
        calculate_next_run()


def execute_script():
    run_selenium_script()


def calculate_next_run():
    global next_run_time
    # Calculate delay time: 2 hours and 2 minutes
    delay_time = (2 * 3600) + (2 * 60)
    next_run_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=delay_time)


def update_countdown():
    global next_run_time
    calculate_next_run()  # Initialize next_run_time
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        if next_run_time and now < next_run_time:
            remaining_time = next_run_time - now
            countdown_string = str(remaining_time).split('.')[0]  # Remove microseconds
            countdown_label.config(text=f"Next run in: {countdown_string}")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            countdown_label.config(text="Initializing...")
            execute_script()
            calculate_next_run()


# GUI Setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Selenium Script Scheduler")

countdown_label = tk.Label(root, text="Initializing...", font=("Helvetica", 16))
countdown_label.pack(pady=20)

execute_button = tk.Button(root, text="Execute Script", command=execute_script)
execute_button.pack(pady=10)

update_countdown_thread = Thread(target=update_countdown)
update_countdown_thread.daemon = True
update_countdown_thread.start()

root.mainloop()

Code Overview:
The Python script utilizes the Selenium WebDriver to automate interactions with a web application. It uses Tkinter for the graphical user interface (GUI) and implements threading to manage the countdown timer and script execution.

The main components of the script are as follows:

run_selenium_script: This function contains the Selenium code to perform actions on the website, such as logging in, interacting with elements, and handling alerts.
execute_script: This function is called when the user clicks the "Execute Script" button in the GUI. It triggers the execution of the Selenium script.
calculate_next_run: This function calculates the time when the Selenium script should be executed next. It sets the global variable next_run_time to the calculated time.
update_countdown: This function continuously updates the countdown timer displayed in the GUI. When the countdown timer reaches zero, it calls execute_script to run the Selenium script again and recalculates the next run time.
Issue:
Despite setting up the script to re-run after the countdown ends, it does not seem to do so. The countdown timer reaches zero, but the Selenium script does not execute again automatically.
Request for Assistance:
I would appreciate any insights into why the Selenium script is not re-running after the countdown timer reaches zero.
Are there any potential errors or oversights in the code that could be causing this issue?
How can I modify the code to ensure that the Selenium script executes again after the countdown timer expires?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
